# standard string rfind not finding period

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, c++17

I am trying to extract the name of file, without the extension or qualified path e.g. extract `file` from `/path/to/file.txt`

I have the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string temp = "dir/filename.txt";
    auto bpos = temp.rfind('/')+1, epos = temp.rfind('.')-1;
    cout << temp.substr(bpos,epos) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `filename.tx` and I am not sure why this is the case. Is `rfind()` just not able to find the period? Escaping the character does not work either, same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is a count of characters, not a position.

Instead, you need something like:

```
temp.substr(bpos, epos - bpos + 1)
```

which computes the count of characters given the 2 positions.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wra9s7).